# extracting data using lxml and request and xpath in Python from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, python-requests, lxml

I am trying to extract some data from a website using lxml and requests in Python.
Here is the [URL](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/HPQ:NYSE?comparison=NASDAQ%3AINTC%2CNASDAQ%3AAAPL%2CNASDAQ%3AAVGO%2CNASDAQ%3AQCOM)

And here is my code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.google.com/finance/quote/HPQ:NYSE?comparison=NASDAQ%3AINTC%2CNASDAQ%3AAAPL%2CNASDAQ%3AAVGO%2CNASDAQ%3AQCOM')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div[4]/div/div/main/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]')
```

However, when I look at the `price` it is empty.
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
The price that I am looking for is the price of some stocks that are in the comparison section. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This page uses a lot of javascript to generate html content.

However if you disable javascript or just inspect the first doc that comes through in web-inspector (for more on that see my [blog entry here](https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html)), you can see an easy way to access the price:

[image]

Which can be achieved with xpath `//*/@data-last-price`:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.google.com/finance/quote/HPQ:NYSE?comparison=NASDAQ%3AINTC%2CNASDAQ%3AAAPL%2CNASDAQ%3AAVGO%2CNASDAQ%3AQCOM')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
price = tree.xpath('//*/@data-last-price')
```

Unfortunately it's a very complicated web-app. For comparison data I'd recommend doing additional request instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you go a little down on the page that I have posted the link of that page you can see prices for stocks like HP, Intel, Apple etc. How I can get those prices?

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot of what I am looking for.